# How can I arbitrarily execute a rule from the UI to test a login togobban workflow using selenium?

Tags: 7, rules, users

I am trying to create tests for my Drupal site using Selenium UI.  I am attempting to test Login Toboggan's "verify user" behavior, but since the account verification link is different each time, it cannot be easily included in a test.

I have several rules that should be triggered upon successful validation; since I cannot trigger validation in the normal manner, I would like to activate these rules manually.  Is there a way to do this from within the UI (so that it can be added as part of selenium)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this with rules by making a new rule.

Event- "User has logged in"

Conditions- "User has roles" -> The role of the "unverified user" (set on the 
logintoboggan configuration screen)

Actions- "Show a message on the site"

Message text:

```
<a href="[account:validate-url]">validate your account</a>
```

This will present a message to unverified users when they log in allowing them to verify their accounts.  Of course this has to be disabled for production, but it allows one to test validation workflows in Selenium.